# Send reminder note one day before delivery date

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, orders

I'm very new to coding and i want to make a function that can send a email reminder one day before delivery date on completed orders in WooCommerce 3.1.1.

I'm using the plugin WooCommerce Delivery Slots and got the information about delivery date here:http://docs.iconicwp.com/article/53-get-the-delivery-date-for-an-order

I don't know how to proceed for making this function work.

```
add_action("init", "send_reminder_note");

function send_reminder_note($order_id) {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

foreach ( $order_id as $id ) {

    //Get all order data
    $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
    $order_id = $order_data['id'];
    $order_parent_id = $order_data['parent_id'];
    $order_status = $order_data['status'];
    $order_billing_email = $order_data['billing']['email'];

    //Get one day before delivery date
    $date = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'jckwds_date', true ); // delivery date
    $date_temp = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'jckwds_date', true );
    $date = date("Ymd", strtotime("-1 days"));

    //Send emils if orders is completed and one day before delivery date
    if($order_status == 'completed' ) {
        if($date_temp >= $date){
            $to = $order_billing_email;
            $subject = 'Reminder your package will be sent tomorrow';
            $body = 'your order will be sent tommorow';
            $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to have understood your question. 
Given your `jckwds_date` field in your orders table is the delivery date,

I'd suggest you to set a cron (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and run it once a day. This cron will run a PHP file with a function similar to the one you wrote but with this flow:

- Query the database where `jckwds_date` == date of tomorrow
- For each order send the confirmation email

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the "WooCommerce Delivery Slots" and got the jckwds_date from: [http://docs.iconicwp.com/article/53-get-the-delivery-date-for-an-order](http://docs.iconicwp.com/article/53-get-the-delivery-date-for-an-order)